# Error Installing Eclipse 3.7.2 Plugins on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, installation

Steps taken in attempt resolve issue:
1-confirmed Eclipse was ran as Admin.
2- moved Eclipse from /ProgramFiles to C:/eclipse

The following error continues to occur:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.javascript, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http: //pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.5.0.2012040618.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http: //pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_2.5.0.2012040618.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.parser_2.5.0.2012040618.jar.
Read timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update python from the software repository again via Software Updates

Answer (score 0):

It's having a network problem reaching this remote machine. If access requires a network proxy, check your preferences to make sure your proxy settings are correct (Preferences -> Network Connections). Alternatively see if the pydev update site stuff is available as a zip file that you can download to your local machine and update from that.